# Rust Embedded panic destroys stack

Tags: rust, gdb, embedded, panic

I'm using Rust on a Cortex-M4 and using gdb with openocd to debug it.

From C(++) I'm used to looking at the call stack when an exception (like a hardfault) happens. It's really helpful to see which line caused the exception.

However, in Rust, when a panic happens, the call stack is almost empty. Why does this happen?

Is there a way to make Rust preserve the stack (only for the debugger, I don't need to print it)? Or can I insert a breakpoint somewhere where the call stack hasn't been destroyed yet?

Right now I have an unwrap somewhere that panics, but I can't find where unless I step through a whole lot of code.

---

**EDIT**: This is the stack trace I do get in the panic handler:

```
i stack
#0  rust_begin_unwind (info=0x2001f810) at src\main.rs:122
#1  0x080219dc in cortex_m::itm::write_fmt (port=0x2001f820, args=...) at C:\Users\d.dokter\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\cortex-m-0.6.1\src/itm.rs:128
#2  0x2001f894 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

It's also weird that the write_fmt function is on the stack as that is being called inside the handler to log the panic. I find that 0x2001f894 address very suspicious as well, because that's a RAM address.

Comment: Are you using concurrency / threading?  When you do that, the exception handler switched to the system stack, so the stack of the interrupted thread will no longer be visible.  That is true in C and C++ too, but perhaps in that case you were not using threading? https://developer.arm.com/docs/dui0553/a/the-cortex-m4-processor/exception-model/exception-entry-and-return

Comment: @Clifford No, only the msp is used and the psp is left at 0 at all time

Comment: I've fixed the problem that caused the panic now, but searching where it happened took way longer than should be necessary... It turns out I forgot a check somewhere

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to set the panic handler to call `abort()` instead of unwinding the stack. This can be done by adding this to your `Cargo.toml`

```
[profile.dev]
panic = "abort"

[profile.release]
panic = "abort"
```

With this setting, the panic handler will immediately call `abort()`, so gdb can still see the whole backtrace.

If you just want to print the stack trace, you can also set the environment variable `RUST_BACKTRACE=1`.

Comment: I see how that would help in a normal environment. But I'm running this embedded and that only compiles if a custom panic handler is present. These settings have no effect, sadly.
https://rust-embedded.github.io/book/start/panicking.html

Comment: @Geoxion In that case, you should set a break point at the beginning of your custom panic handler. Gdb can only show you the backtrace if you allow it to take a look before the stack has been unwound.

Comment: Well, that's the point. If I break in the handler, be it at the start or the end, I don't get a nice stack. Something has happened to it before the handler is called.

Comment: @Geoxion The page you linked says you should put a breakpoint on `rust_begin_unwind`. Is that what you did?

Comment: Yes. Though if I do it through the cli, I get a different call stack. On top is the `rust_begin_unwind` and after that an infinite amount of `core::panicking::panic_fmt`. After a little bit of digging in that I now know that if I put a breakpoint on `core::result::unwrap_failed`, I do still get the full callstack. Gonna look in the source code now to see what happens in between.